# Bash скрипт на копирование файлов определённого расширения и смена верхнего регистра на нижний

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Bash скрипт на копирование файлов определённого расширения из директории(включая подпапки) без сохранения структуры
Существует Ubuntu18, на который сохраняется файлы формата Axxx.xlsx
Я написал след скрипт

```
find -name «*.xlsx» | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | cp /home/vskibenko/tmp/.
```

Но он отрабатывается не совсем четко

Суть скрипта в след
"Копирование файлов из папки и ее подпапок в другую директорию, с изменением названия на нижний регистр"

Comment: Решение вашей задачи намного проще: 1) копируем все файлы как есть (и славо б-гу это очень сильно ускоряет процесс), а затем переименовываем их как хотим, есть, например `rename`, который умеет Perl RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
find -name "*.xlsx" | while read f; do 
  fn="$(basename "$f")"; 
  cp "${f}" "/home/vskibenko/tmp/${fn,,}";
done
```

Замечания:

- Такой вариант не будет работать, если в именах файлов есть переводы строк.
- Расширение переменной с переводом в нижний регистр (`${fn,,}`) — это `bash`'изм и может не работать в других POSIX-совместимых оболочках, например, `dash`.
- Выражение записано в несколько строк для удобство чтения, в таком виде его можно применять и в одну строку.

Comment: Соответственно, если мне надо запускать не в папке с файлами мне строку
find -name "*.xlsx" | while read f; do 
надо изменить на 
find /путь/ -name "*.xlsx" | while read f; do 
?

Comment: @Miekrif, да...

Comment: Почему-то не видит папку на кириллице, выдает ошибку "find: '/home/vskibenko/\303\360\340\364\350\352\350': No such file or directory"

Путь прописан такой /home/vskibenko/Графики/. 
И в кавычки заключил и что локали добавлял, все равно ошибка остается, если поменять на латин, то все исправно работает

Comment: `basename` лишний, прочитайте про замены в shell. `cat ... | while read line; do ... done` конструкция ну очень тормозная, почитайте про `xargs` и `find ... -exec ...`.

Comment: @0andriy, почему ты считаешь, что `basename` лишний? с `xargs`/`find` придётся дополнительную оболочку запускать — синтаксис для однострока будет кривой и правильно заэскейпить все кавычки с первого раза почти невозможно...  про тормознутость — бенчмарк в студию...

Comment: Потому что запуск внешней команды basename не нужен. Ещё раз, почитайте про подмену в shell. `man sh`. И это переносимо!

Comment: Не зря же я упомянул `find -exec ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Пример: копирование `txt` файлов из текущей папки в папку `dst/`

```
ls *.txt | sed -e 's#\(.*\)#cp "\1" "dst/\L\1";#' | bash -s
```

`sed` формирует на лету скрипт, `bash -s` его читает из стандартного входа и выполняет.

Скрипт для моей тестовой папки получился вот такой:

```
cp "A.txt" "dst/a.txt";
cp "b.txt" "dst/b.txt";
cp "c D.txt" "dst/c d.txt";
```

Имена файлов взяты в кавычки на случай пробелов в именах.

Comment: путь dst можно указывать любой? и как поведет себя с папкой на кирилице?

Comment: @Miekrif любой путь без символов `'"#\\` в нём. Кириллица допустима.